# Azure DevOps Dashboard to run inline python and show output as widget

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-dashboard

Using Azure DevOps, you can create YAML pipelines to run python file or inline python scripts. Is there a proper way to show any of the inline python script output to azure dashboard widget?

I couldn't find any extension in the [azure marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) that can achieve this. What are my options here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have to create your own custom widget via an ADO extension.  The framework examples say to use TypeScript.  I have created ADO extensions to be used in pipelines, but not a widget extension.  You might have to create two components: a pipeline to execute and generate the output, and then a widget to read that output.  I would try the route of creating a Widget first encapsulating all of the logic that you want to execute, prefable in TypeScript.

Comment: I'm afraid if the current Azure SDK extension is ready for widgets yet https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/develop/extensions
I can technically use the older SDK to create the widget, but I'm still having trouble finding enough resources to hook up with a REST API for the Azure widget to talk to a custom pipeline, or just a different server (could be just a simple weather API)